# Determine whether two arrays have the same elements with the same multiplicities

Tags: python, algorithm, array

I have written a Python function called `comp` that checks whether two given arrays have the same elements, with the same multiplicities. The multiplicity of a member is the number of times it appears in the array. I would like to post my code here for review, so that I can optimize it and receive any advice on how to improve it.

Here's the code for the function:

```py
def comp(array1, array2):
    c = 0
    ta = []
    if len(array1) == 0 or len(array2) == 0:
        return None
    for i in range(len(array2)):
        for j in range(len(array2)):
            if array2[i] != array1[j] * array1[j]:
                c += 1
        ta.append(c)
        c = 0
    if len(array1) in ta:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

I would appreciate any suggestions or advice on how to improve the code's efficiency, readability, or any other best practices that I might be missing.

Comment: Could you provide some sample input?

Comment: This code doesn't appear to work correctly. Based on the problem description, `comp([1,2], [1,2])` should return True, but it returns False.

Comment: What resource do you want to "optimize"?  Memory, CPU, something else?  There are tags for these, but I don't know which to apply.  (BTW, I removed the "functional programming" tag, as this is clearly using an imperative style).

Comment: Why is this code squaring elements of `array1`?  This code makes no sense to me, and no comments explain why it's doing it that way.  It's highly non-obvious how this algorithm works, although I guess the idea of looking for `len(array1)` in `ta[]` is that it's counting non-matches, so that would find a case where nothing matched?  Seems weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    for i in range(len(array2)):
        for j in range(len(array2)):
            if array2[i] != array1[j] * array1[j]:
                c += 1
```

> The multiplicity of a member is the number of times it appears in the array.

Either the problem is ill-specified, or the code is wrong.

When the lengths of array{1,2} differ,
we either ignore many entries
or we raise IndexError.

It is very surprising for a `bool` predicate
to return `None`.
Consider using `mypy` to help you lint this code.

---

The identifier `c` apparently means "count".
Take the opportunity to spell that out more fully.

What were you thinking when you chose the identifier `ta`??
What should I think when I read it?
No idea what's behind that decision.
Rename it before merging down to `main`.

You chose a `list` datastructure for something that
we only do an `in` test on.
Ordinarily I would encourage switching it to a `set`,
for O(1) constant lookup speed.
But given the crazy quadratic complexity of that loop,
it's lost in the noise.
Instead you should focus on choosing a sensible algorithm
with complexity O(N log N) or better.

---

Given the lack of unit tests and
poor level of specification / documentation,
I would not be willing to delegate or accept
maintenance tasks on this code base.

Comment: it is very good answer thank you

Answer (score 6):

There's no docstring for the function (and it's so generically named, it could easily be mistaken for something else).

There are no unit-tests; they should be trivial to add.

Variable names such as `c` and `ta` might mean something to you now, but it's unlikely they will mean much to the next maintainer (perhaps 6-months-older you?).

It's surprising that a predicate function can return `None`.  If one of the inputs is empty, I'd expect the result to be true if, and only if, the other input is also empty.

It's not clear why we're multiplying `array1[j]` by itself when comparing.  That's going to break the comparison, and should fail our unit tests.

The O(n²) algorithm that searches for matches scales poorly.  We can make it much more efficient (at the expense of increased memory usage) by constructing a *multiset* ([`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)) from each input, then comparing the two multisets for equality.

---

## Simpler implementation

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import collections

def bag_equal(array1, array2):
    """
    True if the inputs contain the same elements (including duplicates)
    in any order.

    >>> bag_equal([], [])
    True
    >>> bag_equal([], [''])
    False
    >>> bag_equal([0, 0, 2, 3, 3], (0, 2, 3, 0, 3))
    True
    >>> bag_equal([0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1])
    False
    >>> bag_equal(["me", "you"], ["me", "you", "you"])
    False
    """

    # Test lengths first, to avoid creating counters unnecessarily
    return (len(array1) == len(array2) and
            collections.Counter(array1) == collections.Counter(array2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Answer (score 2):

Things to check upfront

- same length, else multiplicities cannot all be the same

tools to use

- [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)
  most simple:
  `return Counter(items1) = Counter(items2)`
  one additional Counter instead of two:

  ```
      delta = Counter(items1)
      delta.subtract(items2)
      return not any(delta.values())
  ```
- [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) - useful if the items cannot be hashed (meaning `Counter` won't work)
  `return sorted(items1) == sorted(items2)`

Comment: Inviting everybody to expand or otherwise improve.

Comment: `Counter.subtract()` returns `None`, so you can't chain the `.values()`. `delta = Counter(items1)\ndelta.subtract(items2)\nreturn not any(delta.values())` should work.